# Do formulas involving fewer repetitions of variables give higher numerical precision?

Tags: algorithms, proof-techniques, computation-models, mathematical-analysis, numerical-analysis

I'm having some trouble doing SICP exercise 2.15. Please note that this question is not closed related to Lisp. Instead, it's closely related to numerical analysis.

> [Exercise 2.15.](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-14.html#%25_thm_2.15)  Eva Lu Ator, another user, has also noticed the
>   different intervals computed by different but algebraically equivalent
>   expressions. She says that a formula to compute with intervals using
>   Alyssa's system will produce tighter error bounds if it can be written
>   in such a form that no variable that represents an uncertain number is
>   repeated. Thus, she says, `par2` is a "better" program for parallel
>   resistances than `par1`. Is she right? Why?

This question is a little confusing when pulled out of context, so please let me explain. The formula for parallel resistors can be written in two algebraically equivalent ways: $\frac{R_1R_2}{R_1+R_2}$ and $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R1}+\frac{1}{R2}}$. However, it seems that computing parallel resistors with the second formula would always produce higher precision than using the first one.

My question is:

1. Which formula is better? $\frac{R_1R_2}{R_1+R_2}$ or $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R1}+\frac{1}{R2}}$? Here "better" means provides higher precision.
2. Why it is better than the other one? Please prove your answer to the first question.

---

Here is my effort

> After many experiments, $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R1}+\frac{1}{R2}}$ seems to
>   be the better formula. I guess that the reason behind can be conclude
>   as *the fewer time uncertain numbers are repeated, the less
>   uncertainty is introduced, and the higher precision we can get.*

But that's not enough. I expect a more scientific and more rigorous answer.

Comment: By *repeated*, do you mean *multiplied*?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus In my understanding, "repeat" means "appear more than once" in this exercise. Both R1 and R2 appear twice in the first formula, and only once in the second one, so the second formula is "such a form that no variable that represents an uncertain number is *repeated*"

Comment: I didn't really understand your original title (I thought it had something to do with probability) so I edited. Please feel free to revert if you think your title was better than mine!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I want to say that it is *not* the case in general that an algorithm that minimizes the number of uses of the inputs is more accurate, at least for IEEE 754 floating point.  For example, [compensated summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm).

On the other hand, it's certainly the case that [interval arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic) can *greatly* benefit from knowing when two inputs are identical.  As a trivial example, if $X$ is an interval variable, then logically $X - X = 0$ but of course the subtraction algorithm (usually) doesn't know whether it's inputs are logically identical, and so it must assume the worst-case $$X - X = [X^{lo} - X^{hi},X^{hi} - X^{lo}]$$

This is roughly what's going on here and almost certainly view SICP is taking.  If you use naive interval arithmetic operations, repeated uses of a variable will be treated independently, and so it won't be possible to cancel out error and the worst-case must be assumed.  Using the formulas from the interval arithmetic Wikipedia page and assuming $R_1$ and $R_2$ are represented by intervals that are strictly positive, you can simply calculate:
$$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2}} = \left[\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_1^{lo}}+\frac{1}{R_2^{lo}}},\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_1^{hi}}+\frac{1}{R_2^{hi}}}\right]$$
while
$$\frac{R_1 R_2}{R_1 + R_2} = \left[\frac{R_1^{lo}R_2^{lo}}{R_1^{hi}+R_2^{hi}},\frac{R_1^{hi}R_2^{hi}}{R_1^{lo}+R_2^{lo}}\right]$$

It's clear that $$\frac{R_1^{lo}R_2^{lo}}{R_1^{hi}+R_2^{hi}} \leq \frac{R_1^{lo}R_2^{lo}}{R_1^{lo}+R_2^{lo}}$$ and symmetrically for the upper bounds, so the latter formula has a looser interval.

Comment: This answer is great! However, I think compensated summation mainly deals with the error brought by floating-point arithmetic, on which this exercise doesn't lay much emphasis. Let's assume floating-point arithmetic always gives accuracy result. (Alternatively, let's assume rational numbers are stored as `numerator / denominator` in the memory, so the representation is exact.) In this case, considering only the error caused by interval arithmetic itself, is Eva Lu Ator right?

Comment: As a generally true fact about interval arithmetic, I don't know. I suspect that you *can* prove that it holds for broad classes of expressions. For example, I'm fairly confident that it's true for expressions involving only addition, subtraction, and multiplication.  In general "expressions" can be arbitrary programs for which this statement is almost certainly false.

Comment: To divide two intervals, we can simply multiplies the first by the reciprocal of the second, so I guess the statement holds true for all expressions involving only addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division. I'm glad to perform the proof on my own, but could you give me some hints on how to prove it? You know, even elementary arithmetic can produce a broad class of expressions, and I don't know where to get started. Also, by "arbitrary programs", do you mean weird things like the Dirichlet function?

Comment: I've tried many expressions with more "advanced" functions such as $\log_a b =\frac{\log b }{\log a }$, but all of them show me that "the more *inter-interval operations* (i.e. operations between two intervals) are performed, the more information on precision is lost, and thus the less accurate the result would be". Could you please give me an example of an "arbitrary program" for which Eva Lu Ator's statement is false?

Comment: $\log$ is monotonic so it's not going to cause problems. I didn't state that it was false, though largely because it's not clear what "uses" means in that context nor what the range of allowed operations would be.  As a simple example though, doing Newton's method with intervals diverges but if you "use" a variable an extra time to intersect, it works correctly: http://www2.math.uni-wuppertal.de/~xsc/xsc/node12.html

Comment: The way I'd approach the case I gave, with +,-,* is by noting that such expressions are polynomials and can be put into [Horner form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner's_method). Then attempt to show that every other equivalent expression can be reached from it by transformation that preserve or widen the interval. Either way, I believe, though I haven't thought too hard about it that the only ways duplicate variables can arise are: distributivity, additive inverse (X-X=0), and affine combinations of copies of a variable with non-interval coefficients (arguably, a case of distributivity).

Comment: I'm really sorry to say that, but it seems that our discussion has gone beyond the boarder of what my little brain can understand. I didn't expect things to become complicated like this... While it is true that, technically speaking, every program is comprise of a set of expressions, I think this exercise concerns simple algebraic expressions only. And your Interval Newton Method example is just too unconventional and complicated for a layman like me to understand. Anyway, I've learnt a lot about how numerical things work from your great answer and patient comments. Thank you again!